# How to multiply matrix using pointers - C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have to write a program which multiply matrix using pointers.
My program does it correctly, but there are two problems:

1) I can do only one multiplication - when I want next one there is error

2) when I input data of first and second matrix i have to put one more
 char to make my program work.

What should I change in my code to solve those problems?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

while (z--) {               // the number of sets
    scanf ("%d %d", &n1, &m1);      // first matrix n1 x m1

    int **A = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        *(A+i) = malloc(m1 * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m1; j++) {
            scanf("%d ", (A+i*m1+j));
        }   
    }

    scanf("%d %d", &n2, &m2);       // second matrix n2 x m2

    int **B = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        *(B+i) = malloc(m2 * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
            scanf("%d ", (B+i*m2+j));
        }
    }

    if (m1 != n2) {
        printf ("ERROR\n");
    } else {
        int **C = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int*));        //matrix with product
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            *(C+i) = malloc(m2 * sizeof(int));
        }

        for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<m2; j++) {
                *(C+i*m2+j) = 0;
            }
        }

        for (k = 0; k < n2; k++) {
            for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
                    C1 = 0;
                    A1 = *(A+i*m1+k);
                    B1 = *(B+k*m2+j);
                    C1 = (C1+A1*B1)%1000;
                    temp = *(C+i*m2+j);
                    *(C+i*m2+j) = temp+C1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
                printf("%d ", *(C+i*m2 +j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {      // free third matrix
            free(*(C+i));
        }
        free(C);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {          // free first matrix
        free(*(A+i));
    }
    free(A);

    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {              // free second matrix
        free(*(B+i));
    }
    free(B);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Can you post the missing code?  we cannot see how you invoke the current fragment, esp multiple times.

Comment: Fitstly, you have to make the code compilable by adding definition of function and needed variables.

Comment: The syntax `*(A+i)` is much less readable than its equivalent `A[i]`

Answer (score 1):

You write to memory beyond the allocated size.  This invokes undefined behavior, a good explanation for the erratic behavior you observe.

The offending code is this:

```
    for (k=0; k<n2; k++){
        for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<m2; j++) {
                C1=0;
                A1=*(A+i*m1+k);
                B1=*(B+k*m2+j);
                C1=(C1+A1*B1)%1000;
                temp=*(C+i*m2+j);
                *(C+i*m2+j)=temp+C1;
            }
        }
    }
```

You assume that the matrices are allocated as a single packed 2D array.
Since you allocate them as arrays of pointers to arrays of `int`, you cannot use this code.  Use the much simpler version below:

```
    for (k = 0; k < n2; k++){
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j] % 1000;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is not clear why you compute modulo `1000`.  If you really mean that, you should use this:

```
  C[i][j] = (C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j]) % 1000;
```

If you are not supposed to use the `[]` syntax, replace it with the equivalent for pointer dereferencing, not 2D array addressing.  I understand what they are trying to teach you, but a diagram would be more effective than this.

```
  *(*(C+i)+j) = (*(*(C+i)+j) + *(*(A+i)+k) * *(*(B+k)+j)) % 1000;
```

As you may have noticed, the `[]` syntax is the same for 2D arrays and arrays of pointers to arrays, but the code generated for pointer arithmetic and dereferencing is quite different.

There are other places where you need to change the indexing method, here is the corrected code:

```
while (z--) {                       // the number of sets
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &m1);       // first matrix n1 x m1

    int **A = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        *(A+i) = malloc(m1 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < m1; j++) {
            scanf("%d ", *(A+i)+j);
        }   
    }

    scanf("%d %d", &n2, &m2);       // second matrix n2 x m2

    int **B = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        *(B+i) = malloc(m2 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
            scanf("%d ", *(B+i)+j);
        }
    }

    if (m1 != n2) {
        printf ("ERROR\n");
    } else {
        int **C = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int*));        //matrix with product
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            // using calloc so matrix is initialized to 0
            *(C+i) = calloc(m2, sizeof(int));
        }

        for (k = 0; k < n2; k++) {
            for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
                    *(*(C+i)+j) = (*(*(C+i)+j) + *(*(A+i)+k) * *(*(B+k)+j)) % 1000;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m2; j++) {
                printf("%d ", *(*(C+i)+j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {  // free third matrix
            free(*(C+i));
        }
        free(C);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {  // free first matrix
        free(*(A+i));
    }
    free(A);

    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {  // free second matrix
        free(*(B+i));
    }
    free(B);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: The reason is I can't use '[' and ']' - it is a the requirement in the problem.
Also the numbers in matrix after multiplication can be huge so we have to use %1000

Comment: @lotheof If you can't use certain things then *state that in your question*. We're not mind readers.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it's my first question.
@chqrlie I edited my code as you wrote but I still have the same problems

Comment: @lotheof: can you post the modified code to a paste bin?

Comment: Please do not modify  the posted code semantics.  The reason you still have a problem is because you did not fix the addressing issue in the other places where use implemented the 2D array address computation.